# UIButton image property iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I was wondering if there was any way that I could change the size of the image and also its position within the UIButton?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:playButton];
```

Source: http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/04/create-uibuttonbutton-with-images.html